# Rails conditions don't work for me with includes with nested calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@usages = Quoteproduct.includes(:quote => :event).where(:quote => {:booked => "1"}).where(:quote => {:event => { 'end_at >= ?', @quote.event.start_at }})
```

notice the condition at the end of the last where.

But I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC ... => {:event => { 'end_at >= ?', @quote.event.start_at }})
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace ',' with the '=>' operator

Comment: Then I'll get:
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.end_at >= ?' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

```
...{ 'end_at >= ?', @quote.event.start_at }...
```

I believe this style of condition requires an array.

```
['end_at >= ?', @quote.event.start_at]
```